# Update async MetroDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

How can I update the message or the title of a MessageDialog using await, after a operation it is completed?

```
 await DialogManager.ShowMessageAsync(ViewModelLocator.MainView, "Test connection", message, settings: dialogSettings);
```

After a operation in background is completed I want to change the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the message of a `MessageDialog` that is already showing.

There are two options now:

- Dismiss the dialog you're showing and show a new dialog with the updated message.

or

- Create a custom dialog that can be dynamically updated.